# Adapted Visitor Pattern with two return values in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I want to get a pretty print of a tree path along with a path containing the id's of each node. So basically I want to implement a visitor that creates two results.

I have created the following code variants where all variants traverse the tree upwards to the root to get the desired result path like this:

```
while(node.getParent().isPresent()) {
  displayPath += node.getParent().getDisplayName();
  idPath += Integer.toString(node.getParent().getId());
}
```

with Node as

```
class Node {
  private Optional<Node> parent;
  private String displayName;
  private int Id;

  //constructor and getters
}
```

**Variant 1**

```
class Visitor {
  private String displayPath;
  private String idPath;

  Visitor(Root root) {
    visit(root);
  }

  private void visit(Node node) {
    // traverse Tree and set displayPath and idPath
  }

  //getters for displayPath and idPath
}
```

**Variant 2**

```
class Visitor {
  private String displayPath;
  private String idPath;

  public void visit(Node node) {
    // traverse Tree and set displayPath and idPath
  }

  //getters for displayPath and idPath
}
```

**Variant 3**

```
class Visitor {
  public PathPair visit(Node node) {
    // traverse Tree and create a PathPair to return
  }
}

class PathPair {
  private String displayPath;
  private String idPath;

  PathPair(String displayPath, String idPath) {
    this.displayPath = displayPath, this.idPath = idPath;
  }

  //getters for PathPair
}
```

I've thought about the variants:
1. Ensures that the getters are only called after the visit is done, but it creates a lot of Objects and is somewhat unintuitive for the user (why would Instance creation already visit the root?).

2. Someone could call the getters on the result of another root visit. This seems like a dangerous option.
3. Seems the most clear and avoids errors in my opinion.

I would just like to know if I've overlooked a potential 4th option and whether my thoughts about the 3 variants are correct. Thank you.

Comment: I have adapted the code to make it more clearer hopefully :)

Comment: See my answer for another Variant!

Comment: I don't understand why you claim that variant 1 creates a lot of objects. True, it creates somewhat more than variant 2 if you consider that variant 2 would allow instance reuse, but it creates much less objects than variant 3, which need to create a new instance of PathPair for every node it visit...

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situation, I generally add a static method to my visitor classes that a) create a visitor instance, b) execute it on a model graph and c) return the value object. This is similar to variant 1, but is much more intuitive for user than having the constructor implicitly execute visit.

```
class Visitor {
    public static Visitor giveResultFor(Node node) {
        Visitor visitor = new Visitor();
        visitor.visit(node);
        return visitor; // Or extract the result of visitor and
                        // return that instead of the visitor itself
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private String displayPath;
    private String idPath;

    private Visitor() {}

    private void visit(Node node) {
        // traverse Tree and set displayPath and idPath
    }

    //getters for displayPath and idPath
}
```